# Do moderators have access to users' IPs?

Tags: support, moderators

Do moderators have access to users' IPs?

Apparently the above question alone is such that `'This post does not meet our quality standards'`.

Comment: I couldn't just add the *moderators* tag, so I added the *discussion* tag. If some mod. care to fix this, please do.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Thank you. I read the *support* description and it doesn't fit, so I ignored it. I guess it needs to be rewritten.

Answer (score 6):

Yes: [that and much more](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/how-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator). Follow the link for more screens of diamond moderator tools.

[image: mod tools]

Comment: Just to avoid paranoia, the summary of votes does not tell which posts were voted on, so we don't know whether a particular user voted on a given post, much less if it was an up or down vote.